# @media для XHTML

Tags: html, css

Скажите, пожалуйста,  можно ли задать [[[@media](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal) в Html? Проблема в том, что я вставил спутниковую карту яндекс к себе на страницу, но так как там ширина и высота задаются в html, пример:

```
<script>....................fWuUu0Y&width=850&height=350"></script>
```

Я выставляю ширину и высоту 850x350 для 1680x1050, но тут я теряю возможность выставить для других разрешений! Так как размер карты жестко зафиксирован в html и изменять через css не дает, поэтому [[[@media](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal) не помогает!  Как можно выставить для всех разрешений свою ширину и высоту в html, может, есть свой [[[@media](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal) для html?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/4cowmx25/ - google map

http://jsfiddle.net/57k8usnb/ - yandex map

Answer (score 1):

[[[[@media](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal) query используется в CSS3. Как я понял, вам нужно сделать так, чтобы при определенной длине тела сайта у вас было немного другое расположение элементов.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
  body {
    background-color:#777;
  }
}
```

Этот код будет выполнятся следующим образом. Если ширина экрана меньше или равна 480px, то тело сайта станет серого цвета. Просто вписываете внутрь `@media` разные части сайта, которые хотели бы отредактировать и все. А тестировать нужно очень просто, изменяя ширину окна браузера. Я вам не советую играть с высотой (т.е. `@media screen and (max-height: ***px) { /* условия */ }`) просто потому что это не имеет смысла.

Comment: разжевали и в рот положили :) +

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в стилях после, например, `width:100px;` задать `!important`. То есть `width:100px !important`.